# Positive semi-definite vs positive definite

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

I am confused about the difference between positive semi-definite and positive definite.

May I understand that positive semi-definite means symmetric and $x'Ax \ge 0$, while positive definite means symmetric and $x'Ax \gt 0$?

Comment: yes pretty much.

Comment: I fixed some formatting issues, but you could improve the Question by opening with a mention that you are asking about properties of *matrices*.  In any case I added that as a tag.

Comment: The inequality for positive definite is often given as $x^TAx\ge a\gt0$, giving a positive lower bound.

Comment: Also: for positive definite, that condition only applies when $x \ne 0$.

Comment: @robjohn the OP did not specify that $x$ was a unit vector (and does not seem to be thinking in such a manner), so it should be $x^T A x \geq a |x|^2$ with some fixed $a > 0.$

Comment: @WillJagy: ah, good point. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. In general a matrix $A$ is called...

- *positive definite* if for any vector $x \neq 0$, $x' A x > 0$
- *positive semi definite* if $x' A x \geq 0$.

  - *nonnegative definite* if it is either *positive definite* or *positive semi definite*
- *negative definite* if $x' A x < 0$.
- *negative semi definite* if $x' A x \leq 0$.

  - *nonpositive definite* if it is either *negative definite* or *negative semi definite*
- *indefinite* if it is nothing of those.

  Literature: e.g. Harville (1997) *Matrix Algebra From A Statisticians's Perspective* Section 14.2

Comment: Aren't positive semidefinite matrices already a superset of positive definite matrices? So nonnegative definite and positive semidefinite are the same.

Comment: Yes, they are the same; but as you can read the expression from time to time (in the mentioned literatur or in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282045/three-linked-question-on-non-negative-definite-matrices)), i stated it.

Comment: That's true, but it would be clearer if you combined the two definitions instead of having them in separate bullet points as though they were different. So something like "*positive semidefinite* or *nonnegative definite* if $x^T Ax\ge 0$", and similarly for negative semidefinite / nonpositive definite.

Answer (score 4):

A great source for results about positive (semi-)definite matrices is Chapter 7 in Horn, Johnson (2013) *Matrix Analysis*, 2nd edition.
One result I found particularly interesting:

> **Corollary 7.1.7.** A positive semidefinite matrix is positive definite if and only if it is nonsingular.

Comment: Good answer, but what is a "definite matrix"? Forget the word positive for now, I can't find any answer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix)

Comment: I do not think "definite" on its own has a definition. It just means "positive semidefinite or negative semidefinite". In the quote above "positive definite" is a single expression (like "hot dog").

Answer (score 1):

A symmetric matrix A is said to be positive definite if for for all non zero X  $X^tAX>0$ and it said be positive semidefinite if their exist some nonzero X such that $X^tAX>=0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing answers.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't seen the above existing answer.