# What is the definition of positive semi-definite function in $R^3$?

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

The definition of positive definite function is something like:

> for all nonzero $x\in R^n$ then the quadratic function $V(x)=x^TPx>0$ where $P \in R^n$x$R^n$ is a positive-definite matrix.

for example when I am studing the vector $x=[x_1,x_2]^T$ , the quadratice chosen function $V=0.5(x_1^2+x_2^2)>0$ is a positive definite function.

But in one textbook I have found that for a system with three state, i.e $x\in R^3$ for example $x=[x_1,x_2,x_3]^T$ if we choose the quadratic function as :

$V=0.5(x_1^2+x_2^2)$ then this chosen function is positive semi-definite in $R^3$.

I can't understand why the last function is positive semi-definite in $R^3$ and not positive definite? I thought that because it has been taken only two states i.e $x_1,x_2$ and it has been dropped $x_3$. But I didn't understand the idea of that.

Comment: In your definition you need to say "for all **nonzero** $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$", since $V(0)=0$ always. For the actual question, consider what $V(0,0,1)$ is.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited it. for that actual question, $V(0,0,1)$  is zero. Do you mean accordingly to the definition that V=0 even though that $x_3 \neq 0$ and therefore is not positive definite?

Comment: “Positive-semidefinite” means that $V(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$, while “positive-definite” is the additional condition that $V(x) = 0$ only if $x = 0$. This depends on whether you allow your $x$ to come from $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$, as your example is showing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Positive semi-definite vs positive definite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733726/positive-semi-definite-vs-positive-definite)

Comment: I know the definition of positive semi-definite and definite function but I didn't catch the issue when the $x\in R^3$ while V takes only two variables, the first comment has well explained it to me.

Comment: @HansLundmark if you rewrite your comment as answer I will accept it with pleasure.